# Magento 2 is getting installed with older version

Tags: magento2, version

I have cloned from https://github.com/magento/magento2.git. When I install this I am getting Magento Version Magento ver. 2.0.13. I am not getting any Magento ver. 2.1.x.

Why I am getting the older one as the repository is getting updated regularly?

Comment: Have you try with this link, https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any magento version from github,
Just open github link, [Github Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2).

Now click on **Branch Develop** you have seen one dropdown type box display.

Now click on 2.1 Branches,

[image]

Now click on Tags,
You can choose any magento version from here
[image]

Now click on Clone or Download.

Magento 2.1.6 link, [Magento 2.1.6](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1.6)

Comment: Thanks. but the link just says https://github.com/magento/magento2.git. So when I use `git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git` it will download the older Version.

Comment: @MagentoLearner You can download from that point. I have download 2.1.6 and its working fine. I havent try from command line

Comment: Thanks I can download but I want to checkout it with the latest version. Your answer is very useful by the way.

Comment: Rakesh, I had to run `git checkout tags/2.1.7 -b 2.1` to checkout the latest version i.e. 2.1.7.